# change color of an image using a color picker jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i currently need some help, im using [Jquery Minicolors color picker][1]
and i wanted to implement this png color picker transparency to png images basically color png images without clicking the button preview to apply it basically i want to include it in the jquery Minicolors plugin
i made a demo myself but im not very knowledgeable myself i need help..

let me make myself clear as much as possible, what i want to do is establish Jquery Minicolors color box to change automatically without the need of the preview button being clicked to change the color,i want to implement that change color png image transparency into the jquery Minicolors.

Comment: let me make myself clear as much as possible, what i want to do is establish the Jquery Minicolors color box to change automatically without the need of the preview button being clicked to change the color,i want to implement that change color png image transparency into the jquery Minicolors.

Comment: It's pretty clear to me, he's trying track changes of the color picker without having an apply button. Obviously English is not a strong point, and if you put a bit of effort into trying to help people instead of shutting them down, more people might continue using this site.

Comment: Aesthete  thanks Bro, for helping me out & understanding me, theirs alot of people on here that need help and their should be more people like you around here, also for the people posting negative help thanks alot ! i appreciated it!

Comment: To be clear, I didn't mean that people's _english_ isn't good, I meant that some people find it difficult to get their desires and problems across to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for the **change** event of the color picker and apply changes during the callback.

When you initialize your color picker, supply a change callback that modifies your image.

```
$("pickerElement").miniColors({
  change: function(hex, rgb) {
    // use the values above to manipulate image.
  }
})
```

This function will be called every time you change color.

Comment: Different callback. See edits.

Comment: Ok i will try this out, if i have any trouble ill let you know also ill post my final example in a bit thanks once again.

Comment: Hey mate, i just fixed it now!, Thanks for your help i added the following `changeColor();`and now i just i open the color box color and move around with my cursor and i see a live preview changing color, thanks once again!

Comment: @DeadArtcore - You're welcome, make sure you accept appropriate answers to your question. All the best :)

Comment: I will take your advice thanks once again (: